# Implementing Tab Navigation using the ActionBar and a Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have 3 tabs, of which the 1st one has actual data(a listview) and rest 2 are empty. I was just trying to implement tab navigation.

in Activity's onCreate i have:

```
mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
setContentView(mViewPager);
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter((SlidingFragmentActivity) this,
            mViewPager);

adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab-1"),
            Fragment1.class, null);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab-2"),
            Fragment2.class, null);
adapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab-3"),
            Fragment2.class, null);
```

and the **PagerAdapter** is:

```
public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public PagerAdapter(SlidingFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return (SherlockFragment) Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Here Fragment1 has a listview which gets data from a web server using an AsyncTask.

Fragment2 is just an empty fragment

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {

}
```

**Problem:**

when i select **Tab-2**, then **Tab-3** and comeback to **Tab-2**, **Fragment1's onCreateView** is being called. Though the **Tab-2** shows white screen, **Fragment1's onCreateView** is being called, i checked using logcat.

Didnt i implement **PagerAdapter** the right way?

Comment: That's normal. If you want the `ViewPager` to not destroy the view of the first fragment when you get to the third fragment then try to use the method `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` on the `ViewPager`.

Comment: But why is **Fragment1(which is used in Tab-1)** being called when i clicked **Tab-2(Which uses Fragment2).** Because when i went to **Tab-3**, **Tab-1** is destroyed and going back to **Tab-2** will recreate **Tab-1**??

Comment: It creates the view if it reaches the ofscreen limit to have a view for swiping the tab onto the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this behaviour.

The ViewPager tries to minimize the memory impact that the fragments have. If you use a FragmentPagerAdapter the view of your fragment can be destroyed once it leaves the screen.

Typically the ViewPager will hold the view to the left and the right of the current view in memory to enable fast tab switching.

If you have only say 5 Tabs and you want to have all the views of this tabs in memory you can modify the number of views that are kept with [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29). This method lets you specify how many views are kept for each side. If you have only 5 tabs you could set 4 as offScreenPageLimit to have each view kept in memory even if the user is at one of the outer tabs.

Keep in mind that the views are destroyed for a reason. This is a performance optimization and even if offScreenPageLimit of 10 may work on your device it can crash devices with fewer memory. Set the limit to an reasonable number and implement the [onDestroyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView%28%29) and [oncreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) methods of your fragments correct.